# Remote in Twitter typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

Can anyone give me a real example on how to use remote property of typeahead?
The reason I ask this is that I currently have a large json file which cannot be loaded due to the limit of local storage in browser. I'm using Rails 4.0.